# Why Firebase Crashlytics not showing correct number of crashes?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

Crashlytics report is showing much less crashes than the actual amount. My App has over 20k active users and crashlytics reports only 18 crashes but 97.55% crash-free users.

[Crashlytics Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fBS8.png)

I also implemented Flurry and it shows much more reasonable numbers, but the stack-trace is not as good as crashlytics.

Is there any way to get the correct number of crashes in crashlytics?